# Errors Does not include extension.category

Tags: laravel, error-handling, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

i use...
laravel v10.8
php 8.1
lighthouse v6.10
apollo-client 3.7.16
in lighthouse v5.41 we have extension that include category
i was handle errors with this option...
but in lighthouse v6.10 i can not get errors category
how can i get it?

[image: lighthouse v5.41]

[image: lighthouse v6.10]

Comment: It seems they removed it in version 6, and there's an issue for that on their GitHub [6.0 Removal of category and the absence of a replacement](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/2361)

Comment: Also in the last message of issue, someone created a package (custom formatted) for this issue that bring back category 
https://github.com/oneduo/lighthouse-category-handler

Comment: @AmooAti - your comment is a valid answer and should be posted as such.

Comment: @spawnia Great, I'm happy to hear that you confirmed it and posted it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems they removed it in version 6, and there's an issue for that on their GitHub [6.0 Removal of category and the absence of a replacement](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/2361)

[Here](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#removed-error-extension-field-category) is the developer suggestion to restore it back.

Also, In the last message of the issue, someone created a package for this removal that brings back the category extension [Lighthouse Category Handler](https://github.com/oneduo/lighthouse-category-handler)